# Running SQL whilst creating session and redirecting via php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, redirect

sorry for the rather unhelpful title.. wasn't sure how to succinctly describe it myself.

**Queries**

```
<?php 
// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $username = $_POST["username"]; // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = $_POST["password"]; // filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "dbconnect.php";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT username, admin FROM logins WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
            $username = $row["username"];
            $admin = $row["admin"];

        }
        if ($admin ==2) {
            $coach = $_POST["username"]; // filter everything but numbers and letters
            $password = $_POST["password"]; // filter everything but numbers and letters
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, activity FROM coaches WHERE username='$coach' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
                $id = $row["id"];
                $activity = $row["activity"];
            }
            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
            $_SESSION["coach"] = $coach;
            $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
            $_SESSION["activity"] = $activity;
            header("location: coach-home.php");
            exit();
        } 
        else 
            if ($admin ==1) 
                { header("location: player-login.php"); }
        exit();
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="testlog.php">Click Here $username</a>';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

To help save time, everything worked as it should have until I began entering queries within the (admin ==2) {} bit. I'm trying to get it get the login details already sent, then, once noticing what their admin level is (in this case, 2 = they are admin) it would run another query to create a session for the admin, and take them to the coaches home page.

HOWEVER what appears to be happening is that a session is not being created (duh) as coach-home doesn't see a valid SESSION and as such, redirects me.

What I'd like to know is **a.** if what I'm trying to do is even possible, and failing that **b.** I began working on a redirect-redirect... so after (admin ==2) it directs the person to coach-login, where there is essentially the same query as above, and is then meant to redirect to coach-home. However, the page doesn't do this, instead it says at coach-login and is blank (coach-login.php code below)

**Form at bottom of page (in case this is relevant?)**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="testlog.php">
    User Name:<br />
      <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40" />
    <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
   <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />

     <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />

  </form>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**coach-login.php**

```
<?php 
// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $coach = $_POST["username"]; // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = $_POST["password"]; // filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "dbconnect.php";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, activity FROM coaches WHERE username='$coach' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $activity = $row["activity"];

         }
         $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
         $_SESSION["coach"] = $coach;
         $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
         $_SESSION["activity"] = $activity;
         header("location: coach-home.php");
         exit();
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` inside all files using sessions? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: *"Form at bottom of page (in case this is relevant?)"* - Yes, so many leave it out and is always good to have.

Comment: Why do you have a `while` loop to read the results of a query with `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- hey Fred, yes I have session_start(); in most files, except for coach-login.php (my second method) and a few other pages.

Comment: Did error reporting yield anything? I made an edit to my first comment, in case you may not have seen it. But it needs to be inside all files using sessions, just in case it's not and has sessions variables inside those.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not too sure, I took the code from a previous page which would list 25 results, guess I never thought about it. Would that be a cause of the problem?

Comment: No, it wouldn't cause the problem. It's just confusing, and it's a red flag to me that the programmer doesn't understand what he's doing, he just copied patterns without thinking about them.

Comment: `mysql` is depreciated. Switch to `mysqli` and use the Object Oriented style as well. It will save you typing. Also, you lack the understanding of that `while()` loop which you do your fetch in. That would only render the last result in the loop like that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- nothing happened after adding the error reporting and die statement for mysql.

Comment: *"yes I have `session_start();` in most files, **except** for coach-login.php"* - `session_start();` must also be in "coach-login.php" since there are session variables in there. As I said earlier, `session_start();` must be inside all files using sessions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I literally just realised that before I saw your post, ha! It works now, such a simple fix. Will work on changing to mysqli and getting rid of the redundant while() loop as suggested by others, feel free to post that as an answer so I can choose it.

Comment: @HandsomeJack It has been done. Am glad it was resolved, *cheers*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"yes I have `session_start();` in most files, except for coach-login.php"*

---

As per OP's wish:

`session_start();` must also be in "coach-login.php" since there are session variables in there.

As I said earlier, `session_start();` must be inside all files using sessions.

- This is why the sessions aren't being carried over.